# asp.net web forms tag property

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could somebody tell me if in asp.net web forms is something like `Tag` property like in windows forms.
I want to bind some data to controls that i will be able to identify them later without adding a lot of `if(...) { }` 
To be more specific I'd like to use that tag in building sql `selectcommand` and these tags would be like : `c.City, c.Country` and it would be binded to `checkboxlists`

Comment: Wasn't there a 'hidden' HTML field you could use for such purposes? Sorry, happily not developing for web for a long time.

Comment: I don't see something like this. My idea is only to put this command building in loop, becouse i have 8 these checkboxlists and it would be more elegant that building this one by one.

Comment: Please show us the code that you're having problems with.

Comment: Actually I'm still trying to figure it out. I just have 8 checklistboxes where you can chceck Countries,Cities etc. Then I build some sql select command of them, but without recognizing which checkboxlist is which (is it country or city or other checkboxlist) I can't do it in loop (foreach Checkboxlist in Some_container) . Although i've come up with idea to hold it in ID. I need values like c.City so i hold it like c_City and then replace '_' with '.' when i build select command. I just wonder if there is some simpler solution ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you just invent your own attribute?

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" MyAttribute="Country" >

    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

then in the codebehind:

```
 string myatt = CheckBoxList1.Attributes["MyAttribute"];
switch (myatt) {
 case "Country":
   CheckBoxList1.DataSource = ... etc
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: that's it. huh it seems to be so simple. I didn't think that i can append some own attributes, thanks!!!!!!!