# 'TreeNode' does not contain a definition for 'Tag' and no extension method 'Tag' accepting a first argument of type 'TreeNode' could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

Recently I switched from console application to web-application . In console application I used System.Windows.Forms.TreeView . Now I'm using System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView . So some of the methods are throwing error like 'TreeNode' does not contain a definition for 'Tag' and no extension method 'Tag' accepting a first argument of type 'TreeNode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) .

CODE

```
   (TreeNodeCollectionData.TreeNodeCollectionRow)node.Tag).ObjectType.Equals("XYZ")
```

Now in node.tag it throws error . How to solve this error .

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897987/asp-net-web-forms-tag-property)

Comment: @TaW I saw the solution in the link but it will not work for me . As I saw in System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode metadata tag does this job -> Gets or sets the object that contains data about the tree node . So my question is how am i going to achieve it using System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode

Comment: Afaik WebControls simply do not have a Tag obejct property.  Can't you put the info you need into an attribute?

Comment: @TaW I am new to C# . I don't know if it will work or not . I will try with this .

Comment: Finally I found my solution . How to extend a built-in TreeNode class of the ASP.NET TreeView control . Please go through this link . It worked for me    https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/2527108/how-to-extend-a-built-in-treenode-class-of-the-asp-net-treeview-contro